# Facing folder path issue in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have written one script which is working fine when I execute it by `./script.sh`.

Script path: `/var/script.sh`.

I need to do some action in `/var/project`. For that, I have written this script.

```
cd /
cd /var/project
echo "In folder..."
```

Now I need to run this file using `sudo crontab -e`.

**Crontab -e code:**

```
@reboot /var/script
```

I have also `echo` some message and it prints fine. But as in my above code,
it is not going to my path. It goes to this path.

```
/home/myuser
```

Instead of that path I need to go

```
/var/project
```

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root will use `/home` because it's default path of root.

Give you default path before script executes.

add this code at top of the script.

```
cd /
cd /var
```

Now it'll use you path.